# MariaDB Data Insertion, 2-bytes letters got error messages. Would you take a look at my Codes?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have been moving A DATABASE from MySQL 5.0  (Fedora Core 7)  to MariaDB 10.5 into recent OS Rocky 9.1.   As far as ASCII 1 byte text data go, no problem.   Now, I have plenty of 2-bytes characters in my certain Database.  Russian, Hangul, Japanese, Chinese letters.  I wasn't successful to compile the Data into MariaDB 10.5.   Can I tell MariaDB while I am compiling the Data, please handle the Data contains the 2-bytes Character.   Or I have to adjust the computer's environmental settings to accommodate 2-bytes letters.

Anyway I post the my .sql code.   Would you take a look at?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS editors;
  SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client;
  SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE editors (
  id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  editor_id       SMALLINT UNSIGNED,  
  language        CHAR(100),   
  name            CHAR(250), 
  dummy_field     CHAR(10),  
  PRIMARY KEY(id)              
);

INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('1', 'cn:', 'Gengjie Yang', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('2', 'de:', 'Herb Wirtz', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('3', 'en:', 'Diane Gegala', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('4', 'en:', 'Maurice Barnfather', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('5', 'en:', 'Florence Smith', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('6', 'es:', 'Felix Sutherland', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('7', 'es:', 'Enrique Cob', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('8', 'fr:', 'Gina Loyonnet', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('9', 'it:', 'Dr. John Termini : Daniela Castanotto', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('10', 'kr:', '수김선생 (Sue B. Kim)', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('11', 'pt:', 'Dr. Lilicca Moreira', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('12', 'ru:', 'Тимур Мукминов (Timur Mukminov)', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('13', 'ru:', 'Даша Авдулова (Dasha Avdulova)', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('14', 'it:', 'Grazia Manzone', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('15', 'de:', 'Herb Bauer', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('16', 'en:', 'Bill Reardon', 'ZZZ' );
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('17', 'es:', 'Mario Araujo, Prs.', 'ZZZ' );
```

Then, I got a complaining message from MariaDB stating that the line 22, 24, and 25 caused errors.   While the rest of lines are INSERTed normally.

[image: Error Message during Insertion MariaDB]

[image: Result Review by after Insertion]

It is obvious that errors occurred only at Hangul Letter line 22 and Russia Letter lines 24 and 25.

I don't know how to tell or configure MariaDB 10.5 in order to accept 2-bytes letter smoothly?   Would you suggest any possible way to fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect string value error for unconventional characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72180043/incorrect-string-value-error-for-unconventional-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not just 2-byte characters for Europe, but also 3-and even 4-byte characters for Asia.
- These 6 bytes (shown in hex) `EC8898EAB980`, for example, represent 2 Korean characters `수김`.
- Chinese needs utf8mb4, so don't stop at utf8 (aka utf8mb3).
- If you have those bytes sitting in a column declared to be `CHARACTER SET latin1`, then you have the "Mojibake" problem.
- utf8mb4 can be used to *encode* all languages of the world; you may not need a separate column for *which* language is being stored.
- See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

One of these may work; try each carefully; *there's no undo*.

CHARACTER SET latin1, but have utf8 bytes in it; leave bytes alone while fixing charset:
First, lets assume you have this declaration for tbl.col:

```
col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
```

Then to convert the column without changing the bytes:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(111) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL;
```

Note: If you start with TEXT, use BLOB as the intermediate definition. (This is the "2-step ALTER", as discussed elsewhere.) (Be sure to keep the other specifications the same - VARCHAR, NOT NULL, etc.)

CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 with Mojibake:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create table in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE editors (
 id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 editor_id       SMALLINT UNSIGNED,  
 language        CHAR(100),   
 name            CHAR(250), 
 dummy_field     CHAR(10),  
 PRIMARY KEY(id)              
)
CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' 
COLLATE 'utf8mb4_czech_ci';
```

and then try to

```
INSERT INTO editors  ( editor_id, language, name, dummy_field ) VALUES ('12', 'ru:', 'Тимур Мукминов (Timur Mukminov)', 'ZZZ' );
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/

Comment: Why not use `utf8mb4` for true four byte UTF-8? What's with the Czech collate?

Comment: You are right utf8mb4 is better. Czech collate is  an example. I am from Czech republic. I edited the solution.

Comment: Consider `CHAR(5)` with "language codes" such as "cs-CZ", "en-US", etc.

Comment: Thank you, Rick James and Petr Barandovski.   After reading your comments and Reference link, I started to set up the DATABASE LEVEL declaration of 'utf8mb4'.   Once DATABASE is set to 'uft8mb4', I don't need tell again about CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' in the each TABLE CODE to be compiled.   When I am creating the DATABASE, I say 'utf8mb4'.   That solved all ERRORs.        # mariadb>  CREATE DATABASE  00_contributors   CHARACTER SET = "utfmb4';     That's all.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result after the success.

[image]

Wow, it looks nice.